# How do I setup multiple sites with one database in Drupal 7

Tags: database, multi-sites, installation

My hosting provider limits the number of databases.  I would like to setup several small sites with their own theme, modules, etc.  The scripting for setting up drupal sites from my host provider uses simplescripts.com but when I go to do an install, only Drupal 5 has the table prefix option.  Drupal 6 and 7 installs do not allow the table prefix.

I found this good reference, but it wasn't explicit as to whether or not the Drupal version mattered.  [How do I get Drupal to use table prefixes so I can install multiple drupal installations in the same database schema?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20341/how-do-i-get-drupal-to-use-table-prefixes-so-i-can-install-multiple-drupal-insta)

I guess I don't see how to add the table prefixes to a particular install after the simplescripts.com has made the initial installation.

Is it even possible to setup multiple sites in Drupal 7 using one database? If so, is it a matter of using the simplescripts.com to install the files and then moving the installed files to the location I need them to be in? or must I install Drupal 7 manually for each site?

Comment: Solution http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/20345/7313 will work for Drupal 7.

Comment: As Vic said its possible with a table prefix but it will slow down your sites as data & tables increases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to setup a multiple sites in Drupal 7 using one database.

All though its not optimale. compared to the other option to run it in different databases.

[Drupal multiple sites tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/2622)

[Complete tutorial on setting up sites in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/43816/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to specifically know. Apparently my shared hosting company doesn't make it easy to do it from the scripting it provides, but I will attempt to do for a few small sites that speed and performance are not a factor and where I want to conserve the number of databases that I am allowed.  Thanks so much!