# How do I setup multi sites in Drupal 7 using xampp

Tags: multi-sites

I face a problem in multisite with Drupal 7.34. I'm using windows 7 Os. The steps that I followed are:

**1. Create a database for all sites :** create db of all sites test_db, trial1_db and trial2_db.

**2. Install Drupal :** I installed the drupal 7.34 as usual and name it test.

**3. Tell Windows and Apache about the multiple sites :** Open Windows 'hosts' file in a text editor.  Which is typically in /system32/drivers/etc/hosts. And add following lines:

```
                   127.0.0.1 test
                   127.0.0.1 trial1
                   127.0.0.1 trial2
```

Now in httpd-vhosts.conf file, which is located in c:/xampp/apache/conf/extra. I append these lines at end of the file:

```
                   NameVirtualHost *:80
                   <VirtualHost *:80>
                     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
                     ServerName localhost
                   </VirtualHost>

                   <VirtualHost *:80>
                     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
                     ServerName test
                   </VirtualHost>

                  <VirtualHost *:80>
                     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
                     ServerName trial2
                  </VirtualHost>

                  <VirtualHost *:80>
                     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
                     ServerName trial3
                  </VirtualHost>
```

and make sured that these are not commented in httpd.conf.

```
                LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
                Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**4. Create directories for the sub-sites:** Navigate to c:/xampp/htdocs/test/sites and create the directories 'trial1' and 'trial2'. And copy the default-settings.php file to each directory and rename it to settings.php. And also set the permission of these file. I mean these files are not readonly.

**5. Install the sub-sites :** In an open browser, navigate to `http://trial1` or `http://trial1/install.php`

But here I got "Object Not Found!".

[image]

[image]

I followed the these links also.

https://www.drupal.org/node/288126

https://www.drupal.org/node/1682040

http://www.dratek.com/node/77

[How do I setup multiple sites with one database in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39410/how-do-i-setup-multiple-sites-with-one-database-in-drupal-7)

Comment: Try this too http://webwash.net/tutorials/drupals-multi-site-aliasing-sitesphp.

Comment: Try using hosts file to assign them domain names, like `test1. localdomain` and go by domain names instead of virtual "subdirectories". Not an answer why your setup does not work, but maybe it'll be usable workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Sumit Madan for your suggestion. My issue has been resolved now. I just append these lines in test/sites/default/settings.php:

```
  $sites['trial1.com'] = 'trial1.com';
  $sites['trial1.localhost'] = 'trial1.com';

  $sites['trial2.com'] = 'trial2.com';
  $sites['trial2.localhost'] = 'trial2.com';
```